# Does Extra Attack stack with Haste?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, attack, fighter

At level 5 Fighters get the Extra Attack ability, allowing them to make more than one attack as part of an Attack action.

*Haste* also enables people to make additional attacks.

Do the extra attacks from Fighter lvl 5 and the extra attacks from *haste* stack?

Answer (score 20):

*Haste* specifically says in its description:

> That [additional] action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage.... (PHB 250.)

So you're *haste*d: you Attack with your action, and Extra Attack allows you to make two attacks. Now you take *another* (full) action granted by *haste*, and choose Attack. But *this* Attack is not amenable to Extra Attack--you can only make one weapon attack with it. That's three attacks in total.

---

Related: [Haste spell: what does "one weapon attack only" mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77612/23970)