# Can the Gloom Stalker Ranger's Stalker's Flurry feature be used with the Attack action from the Haste spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, ranger, action-economy

The [*haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) spell states:

> Choose a willing creature [...] it gains an additional action on each of its turns. That action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only) [...] action.

Stalker's Flurry states (emphasis mine):

> [...] Once on each of your turns when you miss with a weapon attack, you can make another weapon attack **as part of the same action.**

If you take the Attack action with *haste*, and miss with the attack, can you then use Stalker's Flurry or does the "one weapon attack only" clause of *haste* overrule using the feature?

Comment: Related: "[Does Extra Attack stack with Haste?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100601)" and "[How does the Bladesinging wizard's Extra Attack feature interact with the additional Attack action from the Haste spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/193075)" and "[Does the Echo Knight fighter's Unleash Incarnation feature add another attack to the additional Attack action from the Haste spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167753)" and "[Haste spell: what does "one weapon attack only" mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77612)"

Answer (score 15):

#### Stalker’s Flurry is not “more specific” than Extra Attack.

Extra Attack reads:

> you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

Stalker’s Flurry says:

> Once on each of your turns when you miss with a weapon attack, you can make another weapon attack as part of the same action.

Both of these features give a second attack to an Attack action. However, *haste* states:

> That action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only) [...] action.

What is the point of saying “one weapon attack only” if every feature that gives an extra attack overrides it? Because *haste* limits the number of attacks you can make with its action, you are limited in the number of attacks you can make with it. *There is nothing in Stalker’s Flurry that makes it “more specific” so that it overrides *haste*’s restriction when Extra Attack does not.*

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that your answer could be summarized as: *With Stalker’s Flurry, once on each of your turns when you miss with a weapon attack, you can make another weapon attack as part of the same action, unless that action was the extra attack action granted by Haste*?