# How does the action economy for a hasted Fighter using action surge work in DND 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter

My player's fighter has just reached 11th level, He duel wields Scimitars. On his normal attack action, he gets 3 attacks plus one additional attack for his bonus action.

If he then decides to use Action surge, on the same turn he is then receiving three additional attacks. As I understand it; action surge does not grant a second bonus action is that correct?

SO if he also happens to be hasted does he get 3 more additional attacks or just 1 additional attack? Haste states that he gets another "action" and as the multi-attack class feature applies would I be correct in my interpretation that he would indeed get 10 attacks that round in 6 seconds?

Comment: To answer the Haste part of the question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77612/haste-spell-what-does-one-weapon-attack-only-mean?rq=1

Comment: Hi kyle, this question is very similar to one that already exists, that is why it has been closed as a duplicate. However there is some slight differences, if you feel your question isn't answered by the other post, you can [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking. Or reply here in the comments and we can help guide you. If it does answer your question, great! Having duplicates isn't a bad thing as it helps other users find the question more easily.

Comment: Alright, that does actually answer my question as I apparently didn't see the "one extra attack" portion of the haste spell. So he would be able to take 8 attacks then and eventually 10 at level 20 if he were hasted and was using an action surge.  Thanks for the help.